# linux kernel: understand how jiffies diff is calculated

Tags: linux, time, linux-kernel

I came across the following code in the kernel:

```
/*
 * Have the 32 bit jiffies value wrap 5 minutes after boot
 * so jiffies wrap bugs show up earlier.
 */             
#define INITIAL_JIFFIES ((unsigned long)(unsigned int) (-300*HZ))

static inline u32 cstamp_delta(unsigned long cstamp)
{
        return (cstamp - INITIAL_JIFFIES) * 100UL / HZ;
}
```

where `cstamp` value is in `jiffies`.

This is the code from `net/ipv4/devinet.c` where IP address per interface is implemented (among other things).

I see that `INITIAL_JIFFIES` macro takes the value of 5 minutes (300) and converts it in `jiffies` (`-300*HZ`), and typecasting ensures correct value wrapping.

But why is it explicitly set to negative value (`-300*HZ`)?

I'm not sure, in what units `cstamp_delta()` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is it explicitly set to negative value (`-300*HZ`)?

It's not a negative value. The value is casted to `unsigned int`, so it's positive, and more precisely exactly `UINT_MAX - 300*HZ`, which means that the final value will be 5 minutes before the maximum unsigned 32bit integer value is reached. This is, as the comment states, to detect errors with parts of the code incorrectly handling `jiffies` as a 32bit value.

> I'm not sure, in what units `cstamp_delta()` returns?

Well, `cstamp - INITIAL_JIFFIES` just calculates the total number of ticks from kernel boot time. Dividing this value by `HZ` returns the total number of *seconds* from boot time. Since the value is multiplied by 100 first though, the final result is the total number of *hundredths of second* elapsed from boot time.

Since `u32` is used as return type, the value returned by this function is of course going to wrap around relatively "soon", in about 1 year and 4 months of runtime (2^32/100/60/60/24/356).

Comment: thanks a lot for explanation. What is the purpose for double type-casting? First time to `unsigned int` and then to `unsigned long` (I assume because `jiffies` are defined as long).

Comment: The first one (`unsigned int`) is just to trim the value to 32bit and do the overflow setting it to `UINT_MAX - 300*HZ`, the second one (`unsigned long`) is to cast to the correct final type.